# Cmd/PowerShell/SQL server: Is there any way to see how long a windows service has been running?

Tags: windows, service, cmd, uptime

So I managed to check if a sevice is running with sc query "ServiceName" | find "RUNNING" or net start | find "Service Name", or in SQL Server using xp_servicecontrol. Is there any way to see the uptime of a service? How can I see the uptime of a service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your service has it's own process name, this should work.

```
PowerShell_v4> (Get-Process lync).StartTime

Friday, October 17, 2014 11:46:04
```

If you're running under svchost.exe, i think you need to grab that from Event Log.

```
PowerShell_v4> (Get-WinEvent -LogName System | ? Message -match 'DHCPv6 client service is started' | select -First 1).TimeCreated

Friday, October 17, 2014 10:10:56
```

For Uptime, just compute time diff.

```
$Start = (Get-Process Outlook).StartTime
$Now = Get-Date
$Now - $Start | Format-Table Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds -AutoSize

Days Hours Minutes Seconds
---- ----- ------- -------
   0     0       2       8
```

or as a one-liner:

```
(Get-Date) - (Get-Process Outlook).StartTime | Format-Table Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds -AutoSize

Days Hours Minutes Seconds
---- ----- ------- -------
   0     0       2       8
```